# Programming Gravity

Tags: java, simulation, game-physics, gravity, 2d-games

I'm programming a game (JAVA) and i would like to add some gravity in. I tried to find a formula or someting like this and there is so different way to do it. I'm looking for a formula who can simulate a realistique gravity and make some rebound when the object is touching the floor. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This isn't a question, go google "game physics Java example code"

Comment: Rebound is done by collision detection. Gravity has nothing to do with it - just modify the speed of the object.

Comment: y(t)=-4.9*t^2 + v_y_0*t + y_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near Earth's surface, the gravitational acceleration of all falling bodies is constant (ignoring air resistance). The formula `xf = x0 + v0*t + (1/2)*g*t^2` will give you the final position `xf` given the initial position `x0`, the initial (vertical) velocity `v0` and the time `t` that the object has been falling. `g` is a constant that technically depends a bit on your elevation and other factors, but is around `9.81 m/s`.

To do rebound, you'll need first to do some collision detection. When you detect a collision, you'll need to compute the vector normal to the surface (easy if your surface is a horizontal plane) and then "reflect" (sort of) your velocity vector *through* that vector (if the normal vector is pointing directly upwards, i.e., you're bouncing off a flat surface, this amounts to inverting the velocity `v`). Note that, to make this realistic, you should probably apply some damping after a bounce: in addition to reflecting the velocity vector, you'll also want to scale it down (depending on how it reflected after the bounce, this could involve reductions in either or both components).

To actually simulate such a scenario, you can use a variety of techniques: either pre-compute a list of points and then run an animation through them, *or* you could simulate all of this using Euler's method or some other numeric quadrature technique (trapezoid rule, Runge Kutta, etc.).

Comment: thx, the gravity is working but if want to make the sprite bounce you say i juste need to inverting de velocity but if I print the formula:

Comment: 200.99 = 0 + (15 * 13.399)1/2 * 9.81 * (13.399 * 13.399) //position Y : 199//
202.499 = 0 + (15 * 13.499)1/2 * 9.81 * (13.499 * 13.499)//position Y : 200//
-203.99 = 0 + (-15 * 13.599)1/2 * 9.81 * (13.599 * 13.599)//position Y : 202//
-205.499 = 0 + (-15 * 13.699)1/2 * 9.81 * (13.699 * 13.699)//position Y : -203//

Comment: hi, i fixe my probleme, i was setting my position at xf and i was suppose to do myPosition.y += xf;